# Control LED strips (SK6805) using Arduino Nano and Lipoly 3.7 V battery

Tags: arduino, led-strip, lithium-polymer

I am creating an LED strip controller with an Arduino Nano and a 3.7 V LiPo battery. As I understand it, the operating voltage of the Nano is 5 V, and the logic voltage is 3.3 V. Furthermore, ([according to the Adafruit site](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/basic-connections)), the SK6805 LED can be used with a 3.7 V power supply and 3.3 V logic.

> "If you are powering your NeoPixels with 3.7 V directly from a LiPoly cell, a 3.3 V data signal is OK"

So, I have attached a simple circuit design diagram, and I would like to know if I am heading in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, I can remove the MT3605 and use an Arduino Nano BLE that operates on 3.3V.